# Converting equatorial coordinates of a comet's pole into cometocentric orbital coordinates I and Phi

Tags: orbital-mechanics

The comet's spin axis orientation is usually reported in equatorial coordinates RA, Dec; however sometimes these are shown in form of the Eulerian angles equatorial obliquity (I), i.e. the angle between the orbital and equatorial planes of the comet, and cometocentric solar longitude at perihelion (phi), measured from the vernal equinox of the comet in the sense of increasing true anomaly to the sub-solar meridian at perihelion. I am looking for the formulas to convert the equatorial coordinates of a comet's pole into I and Phi.
Description is given in: Sekanina, Z. 1981a. Rotation and precession of cometary nuclei. Ann. Rev. Earth Planet. Sci. 9, 113–145.